# Error in calculating G-matrix

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecular-structure, ir-spectroscopy

I have a question regarding the calculation of the $G$-matrix in the classic
"Molecular vibrations" textbook by Wilson (1955, McGraw Hill).

On page 63 it gives an example for the calculation of an off-diagonal term
coupling stretching with bending internal coordinates.
Unfortunately I get a slightly different result when calculating it by hand.

Assume a non-linear triatomic molecule.
Atoms 1 and 2 are on the outside, atom 3 is in the middle.

$s_1$ is the bond between Atoms 1 and 3,
$s_2$ is the bond between Atoms 2 and 3,
$s_3$ is the angle between atoms 1, 2, and 3.

The $s$-vectors are (page 63) given by:

Bond between Atom 1 and 3:
$$
  \vec{s}_{11} =  \vec{e}_{31}
$$
$$
  \vec{s}_{13} =  -\vec{e}_{31}
$$
$$
  \vec{s}_{12} = 0
$$
Bond between Atom 2 and 3:
$$
  \vec{s}_{21} =  0
$$
$$
  \vec{s}_{23} =  \vec{e}_{32}
$$
$$
  \vec{s}_{22} = -\vec{e}_{32}
$$
Angle over Atoms 1, 3, and 2:
$$
  \vec{s}_{31} = \frac{\cos(\phi) \vec{e_{31}} - \vec{e}_{32}}{r_{31} \sin(\phi)}
$$
$$
  \vec{s}_{32} = \frac{\cos(\phi) \vec{e_{32}} - \vec{e}_{31}}{r_{32} \sin(\phi)}
$$
$$
    \vec{s}_{33}
  =
    \frac{
      (r_{31} - r_{32} \cos(\phi))\vec{e}_{31}
      + (r_{32} - r_{31} \cos(\phi))\vec{e}_{32}
    }
      {r_{31} r_{32} \sin(\phi)}
$$
If I calculate $G_{13}$ I get:
$$
    G_{13}
  =
    \mu_1 \vec{s}_{1, 1} \cdot \vec{s}_{3, 1}
    + \mu_2 \vec{s}_{1, 2} \cdot \vec{s}_{3, 2}
    + \mu_3 \vec{s}_{1, 3} \cdot \vec{s}_{3, 3}
$$
$$
  =
    \mu_1 \vec{e}_{31}  \cdot \frac{\cos(\phi) \vec{e_{31}} - \vec{e}_{32}}{r_{31} \sin(\phi)}
    - \mu_3 \vec{e}_{31} \cdot \frac{
      (r_{31} - r_{32} \cos(\phi))\vec{e}_{31}
      + (r_{32} - r_{31} \cos(\phi))\vec{e}_{32}
    }
      {r_{31} r_{32} \sin(\phi)}
$$
(EDIT: in the following equality I wrongly assumed $\vec{e}_{31} \cdot \vec{e}_{32} = 0$)
$$
  =
    \mu_1 \frac{\cos(\phi)}{r_{31} \sin(\phi)}
    + \mu_3 \cdot \frac{
      (r_{32} \cos(\phi) - r_{31})
    }
      {r_{31} r_{32} \sin(\phi)}
$$
$$
  =
    \mu_1 \frac{\cos(\phi)}{r_{31} \sin(\phi)}
    + \frac{\mu_3 \cos(\phi)}{r_{31} \sin(\phi)}
    - \frac{\mu_3}{r_{32} \sin(\phi)}
$$
$$
  =
    (\mu_1 + \mu_3) \frac{\cos(\phi)}{r_{31} \sin(\phi)}
    -  \frac{ \mu_3 } {r_{32} \sin(\phi)}
$$

The result in the book is instead:
$$
G_{13} = -\frac{\mu_3 \sin(\phi) }{ r_{32} }
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was that I read the $$\vec{e}_{ij}$$ vectors as if they were canonical vectors.
Especially I implicitly assumed that
$$\vec{e}_{31} \cdot \vec{e}_{32} = 0$$
Which is of course wrong.
If one inserts
$$\vec{e}_{31} \cdot \vec{e}_{32} = \cos(\phi)$$
the correct expression is obtained.